# Using float left and right, right container still slides under left contain on a mobile device

Tags: css, css-float

I have this issue that is only affecting my site when it is displayed on a mobile device.

On a desktop browser, it looks like this:

> My Wonderful Game                     X
>
> PriceHistory

However, on mobile, the Close 'X' button appears under the title, like this:

>

> My Wonderful Game
>
> ```
>          X
> ```
>
> Price History

My CSS:

```
 #TitleContainer {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

 #CloseControl {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.PriceHistory {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="GameDetailsSection">
    <div id="TitleContainer"> My Wonderful Game </div>
    <div id="CloseControl"> <button onClick={hide}> X </button></div>
    <div className="PriceHistory"> Price History </div> 
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it so the "X" (`#CloseControl`) is always in the top right?

Thanks

Comment: Put the `X` next to the text in the markup ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak but then it looks to close to the title on a regular browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the added width of both elements exceeds the screen width, the second one will be displayed under the first one. There are two thing you might do:

1.) Change the order, so that at least the right-floated "X" always stays on top.

or (probably better):

2.) Define the width of the left-floated element as follows (note: This example is based on a width of 30px for the "X" element - just change that according to your needs!): `width: calc(100% - 30px)`. That way the left-floated element always is 30px less wide than the full width, which would allow a 30px wide element (the "X") to float right of it.

Note: Don't forget to use `box-sizing: border-box` on both elements to include paddings and borders in the width calculation.

Comment: Thanks, so would this replace the float left and float right?  Or I still need that?  thanks

Comment: Yes, you still need the float settings. But alternatively, you could put both of these into a wrapper element and apply `display: flex` to that.

Comment: Oh ok, so just a parent <div> just for those 2 containers?  Thanks!